# Close build panel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I run a build in Visual Studio code, a panel pops up with my build output.

Is there a way I can close this panel with a keyboard shortcut?

In Sublime Text, I just hit esc and it closes. Can this behaviour be mimicked in VSCode?

Comment: PS. How does VSCode expect to sell themselves as a slick editor, when I have to keep grabbing my mouse like a muggle?

Comment: Quoted @Scorb in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124771

Answer (score 5):

You can define a shortcut for hiding the current terminal

For instance, mine is:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
}
```

Or you can set one for

```
{
  "key": "escape",
  "command": "workbench.action.closePanel"
}
```

The last one will imitate your SublimeText experience.

Comment: But will the last one overwrite existing VSCode escape behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on my own VSCode instance.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, I also miss this behavior from Sublime Text, and Visual Studio (not Code) - as remembered. If you look at the present default key bindings in Visual Studio Code, you can see that some effort has been made in this direction - if somewhat confused. Filed an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124771

Got feedback from the VSCode folk, and they offered a key-binding, which I currently use.

```
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && panelVisible"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding new `Escape` shortcuts is dangerous, because it will break many default VSCode behaviours.

I would rather use `` Ctrl+` `` instead of `Escape` to do this work, witch is the default shortcut to toggle terminal panel both in Sublime Text and VSCode.

By default, if you were not focused in terminal panel currently (say you were in OUTPUT panel, DEBUG CONSOLE panel...), you would need to press `` Ctrl+` `` for 2 times: the first time to switch to terminal panel, the second time to toggle off terminal panel.

This behaviour doesn't feels good. What we actually want is to **press `` Ctrl+` `` only once to toggle the whole panel**. To do this, here is my configuration in `keybindings.json`:

```
[
    // disable default shortcut for toggling panel
    {
        "key": "ctrl+j",
        "command": "-workbench.action.togglePanel"
    },

    // disable default shortcut for toggling terminal panel to release "Ctrl+`"
    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_3",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
    },

    // set "Ctrl+`" as new shortcut for toggling panel
    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_3",
        "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using VS Code since version 1.60 and `ctrl + j` seems to be the default shortcut for minimizing the build/terminal/problems panel.